# Proportional Area Chart (Square) with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, charts

I am searching a way to do the following charts with D3.js and as I'm new to this, I have no idea at the moment how to sort the squares. 
Tried some research for charts like this:

[image]

[Square chart](https://img.scoop.it/Fo1br4dofqmZ6TYPl8jPuTl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVvK0kTmF0xjctABnaLJIm9)

[image: Example from datavis project]

[Proportional Aera Chart](https://datavizproject.com/data-type/proportional-area-chart/)

but I did not find anything regarding D3.js. 
Does anyone have an idea how to start or proceed?

I think I could manage to create an area with all squares in the right dimensions, but I do not know how to sort them dynamically, so they would group together automatically as shown especially in the first image, when their sizes do not match perfectly but differ a lot.

Thanx for any help, hirschferkel

Answer (score 2):

This example from Mike Bostock is, I think, the sort of thing you're after:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8fe6fa6ed1fa976e5dd76cfa4d816fec

Comment: thanks for your idea. Actually that's not the same. The treemap from Mike will create areas with different sized rectangles, which have different relations regarding width and height. It would be absolutely important to only use squares and therfore the example from Mike doesn't work, afaik...

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly came accross maybe a similar chart: It's called demers cartogram. There is a way to create it in d3.js but it does not look as good as Arc Gis creates it, where the alignment of squares looks much cleaner.

[Demers Cartogram with d3.js](https://bl.ocks.org/martgnz/18583329ac05726c45c367f3b448d5d7)
[image: Demers Cartogram with d3.js]

[Demers Cartogram with ArcGis](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=d1663c61ba2843f78cec5286a4c7a1c6)
[image: Demers Cartogram with ArcGis]